# Smarty 2: Call array with string as key

Tags: arrays, dynamic, key, smarty, smarty2

I have this array `{$man_data}` which is structured like

```
10 > 'Text 8'
14 > 'Text 12'
24 > 'Text 13'
```

and `{$entry.client_id}` returns an integer (10, 14 or 24). I can't figure out how to call $man_data with key $entry.client_id?

I tried: `{$man_data.{$entry.client_id}}`, `{$man_data.{entry.client_id}}`, `{$man_data.$entry.client_id}`... any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
{$man_data[$entry.client_id]}
```